# How to normalize image to remove brightness variations

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

In computer vision course the teacher says that first of all image should be normalized to remove brightness variations.
The link for the video https://youtu.be/0WNiYrRjJbM

The formula looks like below:

`I = I/||I||, where I is an image, ||I|| is the magnitude of this image.`

Could somebody explain how to implement this normalization using python and any library, opencv for instance. May be there is already exists such function in some library and ready to use?

What I think is the magnitude of an image calculates like `m=sqrt(sum(v*v))`, where v - is the array of values for each point after converting image to hsv. And then `I=v/m`, each point value divided by magnitude. But this doesn't work. It looks strange.

Thanks.

Comment: teacher is overgeneralizing.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'm not sure.

Comment: ah, teacher isn't overgeneralizing, teacher talks about an *appearance matching* algorithm! -- did you know about numpy? their docs have a tutorial. work through it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Which tutorial? Could you please post a link?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html and then you just apply `np.linalg.norm` to your image. that'll calculate the 2-norm by default. don't be surprised if that results in a largeish value, making your image's values very small. that is not bad as such.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you for the response. I wrote a little post below. Could you please look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the small code i wrote which does image normalization.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("../images/segmentation/peppers_BlueHills.png")
print("img shape = ", img.shape)
print("img type = ", img.dtype)
print("img[0][0]", img[0][0])

#2-norm
norm = np.linalg.norm(img)
print("img norm = ", norm)

img2 = img / norm
#here img2 becomes float64, reducing it to float32
img2 = np.float32(img2)
print("img2 type = ", img2.dtype)
print("img2[0][0]", img2[0][0])

cv2.imwrite('../images/segmentation/NormalizedPeppers_BlueHills.tif', img2)
cv2.imshow('normalizedImg', img2.astype(np.uint8))

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
exit(0)
```

```
The output looks like below:
img shape =  (384, 512, 3)
img type =  uint8
img[0][0] [64 29 62]
img norm =  78180.45637497904
img2 type =  float32
img2[0][0] [0.00081862 0.00037094 0.00079304]
```

The output image looks like black square.
However it's possible to equalize brightness in Photoshop for instance, to see something.
Each channel (R,G,B) becomes float and only tiff format supports it.

To me it's still not clear what it gives us to divide each pixel brightness by some value, in this case it's 2-norm value of an image. It just makes an image too dark and unreadable. But it doesn't equalize brightness to make it even across entire image.
What do you think about?